# WPF - Update "System.Windows.Controls.Image" from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls

I get this exception on that code.
How to fix it?

Excepton:

> The calling thread cannot access this
>   object because a different thread owns
>   it.

Code:

```
    void CamProc_NewTargetPosition(IntPoint Center, System.Drawing.Bitmap image)
    {
        IntPtr hBitMap = image.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bmaps = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            labelX.Content = String.Format("X: {0}", Center.X); //OK Working
            labelY.Content = String.Format("Y: {0}", Center.Y); //OK Working
            pictureBoxMain.Source = bmaps; // THERE IS EXCEPTON
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);

    }
```

pictureBoxMain is System.Windows.Controls.Image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can freeze the BitmapSource so that it can be accessed from any thread:

```
void CamProc_NewTargetPosition(IntPoint Center, System.Drawing.Bitmap image)
    {
        IntPtr hBitMap = image.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bmaps = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        bmaps.Freeze();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            labelX.Content = String.Format("X: {0}", Center.X);
            labelY.Content = String.Format("Y: {0}", Center.Y);
            pictureBoxMain.Source = bmaps;
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could Freeze the image, as suggested in another thread, which gets rid of the threading restriction but makes the image immutable.

[WPF/BackgroundWorker and BitmapSource problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128438/wpf-backgroundworker-and-bitmapsource-problem)